# Iterating through a nested table and printing column values to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, html-table, headless

Beginner programmer starting out with testing a headless webscraping python and selenium program that prints out data from a specific column in a nested table to the console.

My tests have been successful up until I tried to run the follow code

```
for row in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[2]/tbody/tr"):
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[4]"):
        link = cell.find.element_by_tag_name("a").text()
        pp.pprint(link)
```

The error message I get is 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'find'

I've consulted other guides on referencing data in a nested table, and can confirm the xpath is correct as I am able to print strings to the console as long as I was only looking for one element. The issue seems to arise as soon as I tried this for loop to loop through the rows until the end of the table.

For reference, I'm trying to print the hyperlink text found in cell 4 of each row until the end of the table. If possible, I'd even like to start iterating from the 2nd row, as the first tr is just header information I do not need

```
|cell 1|cell 2|cell 3|Hyperlink|cell 5|
|cell 1|cell 2|cell 3|Hyperlink|cell 5|
|cell 1|cell 2|cell 3|Hyperlink|cell 5|
...
etc.
```

Aside from the importing and headless browser and webDriver set up, this is the only code in the project so far. Eventually I would like to have the hyperlinks I'm looking for opened in a "new tab", to then begin a similar process, but I'm starting with baby steps here. I'd like to just confirm that I can print these links and reference the correct data before I do anything more advanced.

Thanks